# Best way to find the confidence interval of a kernel-density estimate in python / scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am currently estimating the probability density function of my data, which is not normally distributed in general. I do this with [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), and I want to find the confidence interval for the estimated distribution.

I have not found any method or function in scipy documentation to do that, so currently I am getting the confidence interval by integrating the estimated pdf and optimizing it numerically to obtain the desired confidence level:

```py
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar
import numpy as np

# example data
data = np.random.randn(10)

kernel = gaussian_kde(data)

# function that return the confidence:
def f(x):
    return kernel.integrate_box_1d(-x, x) - 0.95

def fprime(x):
    return kernel(x) + kernel(-x)

sol = root_scalar(f, fprime=fprime, x0=0, method='newton')

print(sol.root)
```

(I know this is not the maximum-likelihood confidence interval, but I am interested in a symmetric one)

Is there any better way to do that?